# PHP PDO Keep Getting Error: Charset=UTF8 : An invalid keyword charset was specified in the dsn string

Tags: php, sql, utf-8, pdo, character-encoding

I keep getting this error : PHP PDO : Charset=UTF8 : An invalid keyword charset was specified in the dsn string.

My code is like this

```
function ConnectToSQLAndGetDBConnSTRVar() {
    try {
    $dbname = "irina";
    $serverName = ".\SQLEXPRESS";  
    $username = "USERNAME";
    $pw = "PASSWORD"; 
    $dbh = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database=$dbname;charset=utf8","$username","$pw");
    return $dbh;
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
    }    
}
```

And it doesnt matter how I write utf8.. UTF8 or UTF-8 or utf-8 none of them work for me..
So what do i do please help me..

Comment: Do you really show your login information here? ;)

Comment: @djot Well spotted. It's a local SQL Express server, though, so presumably just dev kit.

Comment: as IMSoP said its a local server.. so it doesnt rly matter and ofc im going to change that simple password..

Answer (score 4):

You can find the parameters accepted in the DSN string [on this page of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php).

There is no `Charset` parameter in DSNs for the "SQL Server" PDO driver (with the DSN prefix  `sqlserv:`).

Bear in mind that all PDO drivers have different DSN conventions, as they are passed directly to the driver and not normalised by PDO.

There is an alternative PDO driver for SQL Server called "PDO_DBLIB", which [does take charset as a DSN parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php), but it has the prefix "sybase:", "mssql:", or "dblib:", depending on compilation options.

Comment: Sorry. Totally misread that. Deleted my obviously wrong comment.

Comment: Hey can you help me on how I install this on my IIS local server? i downloaded from here http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_DBLIB a tgz file and i have no idea how i install this on my IIS local server..

Comment: The built-in SQL Server driver uses UTF-8 by default.  There's no need to install some other driver in order to use UTF-8, and no need to specify the encoding in the first place unless you're using something other than UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error while following the instructions from [here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)  to prevent sql injections 
reading [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) - it is said that prior to php 5.3.6 charset was ignored, and you can use it including options:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
// Set options
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,//can help to improve performance
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //throws exceptions whenever a db error occurs
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES uft8'  //>= PHP 5.3.6
);

try {
    $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
}
catch ( PDOException $e ) {

    $this->error = $e->getMessage();
}
```