# How to set charset in mssql_connect?

Tags: php, pdo, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using `PHP 5.3` on `FreeBSD`.
I want to select some `utf-8` data (persian characters) from `SQL Server` database, and **write them to a text file**, but because of `utf-8` does all the characters will be written to file  ????.
I have searched for two days and read most of the solutions, including:

1. [PHP + SQL Server - How to set charset for connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322421/php-sql-server-how-to-set-charset-for-connection)

In this question someone says that "There is no Charset parameter in DSNs for the SQL Server PDO driver" and suggests using `DBLIB` driver, but [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) I found that that cannot using dblib.

2. [PHP PDO Keep Getting Error: Charset=UTF8 : An invalid keyword charset was specified in the dsn string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948478/php-pdo-keep-getting-error-charset-utf8-an-invalid-keyword-charset-was-specif)

What should I do? Using `mssql_connect` or `PDO SQL Server Driver`

Also I found  that in [sqlsrv_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) we can set `Charset` parameter to `UTF-8`, but I have got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()`.

Comment: When you run a query on ssms, do you also get question marks or do you get the actual characters?

Comment: I get the right and actual characters on ssms.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is the php, not the sql server. I know nothing about php so I can't help, but I'm sure you are not the first guy that tried using php with utf-8, so someone else is sure to have a solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it.
I have used `ODBC Driver` for connecting to `SQL Server` and then do the `SELECT`.

```
$pdo = new PDO ("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname; Uid=$username;Pwd=$pw;");
```

> Note: I did this connection in my test environment (Windows 7) and not on
>   FreeBSD.